# Software for tracking copying, deleting and moving files

Tags: windows, logs, usb

I have seen a lot of questions concerning USB File Transfers and logging them on https://superuser.com/. 
Questions like: [1](https://superuser.com/questions/596030/usb-file-transfer-log), [2](https://superuser.com/questions/815962/tracking-files-downloaded-to-usb-post-event), [3](https://superuser.com/questions/629834/keep-track-of-external-files), [4](https://superuser.com/questions/318577/can-a-file-transfer-to-a-usb-pen-drive-be-tracked-in-windows-7), [5](https://superuser.com/questions/677723/track-down-flash-drives-that-my-laptop-has-accessed), [6](https://superuser.com/questions/393066/how-to-track-the-usb-storage-devices-connected-to-my-windows-server-2008r2-machi)

USBDeview, Nessus, AutoIt script, Windows XP registry were answers to the questions. I found one program that analyze USB traffic also, it's called [USBTrace](http://www.sysnucleus.com/) (I am not in any way affiliated with programs that I've mentioned).

Is there a program that can log all copying, deleting and moving of files from disk that is monitoring? A simple log that would state user, time, file copied, from where, to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[DiskPulse](http://www.diskpulse.com/) is a real-time disk change monitoring solution allowing one to monitor one or more disks or directories, [save reports and disk change monitoring statistics](http://www.ultraimg.com/images/4356757bac.jpg), export detected changes to a centralized SQL database, execute custom commands and send E-Mail notifications when unauthorized changes are detected in critical system files.